# What "32-bit boundary" means?

Tags: network

As a non English speaker, I'm not sure to understand this sentence :
"Padding bytes are added at the end of the Packet Data Field to align the Packet Data Field to a 32-bit boundary".
For me, "boundary" means something like "limit".

Does that mean that the Packet Data Field size in bits will be a multiple of 32 (with padding if needed)? Or padding will be added to the Packet Data Field if its size is lower than 32 bits, to have exactly a size of 32 bits (which is the size limit)?

Thank you!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The "alignment to the 32-bit boundary" means that the field starts and ends at an offset that is a multiple of 32 bits: 0, 32, 64, 96, ... bits from the beginning of the packet. In this case, the data field is padded to become a multiple of 32 bits. (It's slightly ambiguous - could also mean that it just ends at a multiple of 32 bits.)